# Global Section of a Integral Affine Scheme a Field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring with a module structure over a field $k$ and $X= Spec(A) =\{*\}$ an integral ($k$-)scheme. I want to deduce that then $A$ is under this conditions already a field.

Seemingly it's clear because by definition of integer schemes the global section $A= \mathcal{O}_A (X) =A$ is integer and the unique prime indeal is $0$. So I think that that's enough to conclude that $A$ is afield, isn't it?

My problem is that I recently read that to conclude that $A$ is a field I need futhermore the condition $dim_k(A) < \infty$ (as $k$-module). So I want to know why this condition is necessary?

Comment: The result that you need is the following: An integral domain that is finite dimensional over a field is necessarily a field. Without the finite dimensionality hypothesis $k[t]$ is a counterexample.

Comment: ...and this follows by injectivity of the multiplication map with arbitrary element?

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is not invertible, it is contained in a maximal ideal which is prime, this ideal is zero, so $x=0$  and $A$ is a field.

Comment: Yes, indeed this is the striking argument using the uniqueness of prime ideal $0$. What I don't understand is the nesessarity of the "$dim_k(A) < \infty$" condition as I mentioned above.